# Please reopen this question about a programming tool

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, reopen-closed

Please reopen
[Can I display a file with ANSI color escape sequences in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339982/can-i-display-a-file-with-ansi-color-escape-sequences-in-visual-studio-code) because I think it is on-topic.

This question asks about a popular tool, and therefore satisfies the third bullet point listed at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (as well as the fourth bullet point):

> - software tools commonly used by programmers;
> - and is
>   a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

There is even a useful answer given in the comments section.

Comment: It seems like you are asking for an extension, which would go under the reason of "asking for external tools".  Questions that ask how to _use_ a common software tool are acceptable, but questions that ask for tools are not acceptable.

Comment: That question would be suitable for Software Recommendations https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but is definitely off topic on Stack Overflow, because it asks for tools.

Comment: I think the part that asks for *extensions* makes the question off-topic (as Seeking Recommendations). If you rephrase it to "how can I ..." then I think it's on-topic, since there may be some setting in VSCode that allows you to do what you want. Answers that suggest extensions would still be ok, so long as they explain how to use the extension.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The question is not actually asking for tools (unless you mean the part about *extensions*, which I think can be edited out). The tool is specified as VSCode, and the question is asking how to set up the tool to do something.

Comment: _"Post Closed <...> occured Aug 28 '18 at 22:08"_ Do we really need to dig up old posts like that?

Comment: @Cerbrus: It would be necroing if it was a post no one had seen in years. But this post has been getting hits every day and upvotes & comments every now and then (as recently as **2 days ago**) since it was closed. It's certainly not old according to the people finding and upvoting it. I bet Jeff found the question under the same circumstances and is asking this meta question for that reason. The alternative would be to post a duplicate question, which isn't ideal...

Comment: Or just leave it closed...

Comment: If they believe it should stay closed, yes. Don't strawman this, please.

Answer (score 7):

Questions about how to use programming tools are on-topic, so long as it's a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development. Visual Studio Code is a tool primarily used for programming, and caring about how the ANSI color escape sequences are rendered seems to be something that pretty much only software developers would care about. The requirement also appears to be sufficiently narrowly scoped.

One issue with the question is the last sentence

> Is there an extension that would let me do it?

This does look a lot like a request for recommendations, and that's off-topic. However, simply rephrasing it to ask *how* to do what is wanted would be fine. So I've edited the last sentence to say

> How can I do this?

and cast a reopen vote.

Note that asking *how* to do something doesn't preclude answers that suggest extensions. Even if the question can't be solved by inbuilt settings, the question would be fine, since those settings may be added at a later date. The answers still need to be more than just links to extensions, but if they explain how the extension should be used, they are valid answers.

As another example, here's a fairly similar question [Automatically hard wrap lines at column in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122175) that asks how to do something in VSCode. Note that the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45839079) suggests an extension, but that's perfectly fine, since it explains how to use it.

Comment: I'm not too convinced this isn't a request for an extension any more... Sure, it's not _literally_ asking for an extension, but as it's a feature that's clearly not available in the default IDE, what is the question asking for, if not an extension? Your edit removes the research the OP did, in which he figured out he'd need an extension...

Comment: I am not big fan of opening recommendation questions that are clearly off topic, by trying to make them look on topic, where the only answer would be tool recommendations. I am not going to jump and close similar questions that already have answers, but we seriously don't need more recommendation questions around, especially when there is Software Recommendations site.

Comment: @Cerbrus "*removes the research the OP did*" is a bit of a stretch. I think it's much more likely that the OP simply didn't know that asking for extensions is off-topic. Anyway, guessing what the OP meant is not particularly useful. My edit was just trying to make a post that's borderline off-topic into an on-topic question.

Comment: The OP clearly figured out he needed an extension. The question wasn't borderline off-topic. It was a _clear_ request for a tool. You turned that into questionably on-topic...

Comment: @Cerbrus Clearly your ability to read into the intent far outstrips my own. Now I'm curious, is the other example I linked in the answer also off-topic? It also asks for a feature that is not available by default, and the answers suggest extensions. Is that question ok if the OP doesn't know that there are no inbuilt settings?

Comment: Please, leave your sarcasm at the other side of your keyboard.

Comment: @Cerbrus I wasn't being sarcastic. I sincerely don't understand how "*Is there an extension to do it?*" implies that the OP put in any research into figuring out that there's no inbuilt solution. I'm perfectly willing to admit that you have more experience in these matters, and that the sentence is actually sufficient to show that the OP in fact *knows* that there isn't any inbuilt setting to do what they want.

Comment: I've never heard of a developer that would ask for an extension before checking or asking for a built-in option...

Comment: @Cerbrus Clearly you've not met the average question asker on SO ;) But seriously, does the research effort of the OP really matter anyway? The question really does seem to be on-topic to me, and if the only hindrance is the sentence mentioning *extensions*, then editing that out seems like a reasonable thing to do. If the question said "I don't want settings, I *only* want extensions", then I'd agree it's off-topic, but with the phrasing as it was before my edit (and after) I think it allows for either.

Comment: _"does the research effort of the OP really matter anyway"_ hundreds of easily googled questions dumped on SO every day say: _"Yea, it definitely does"_

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't follow. There are 3 types of research effort 1. Is the question easily googleable? If yes, then it's a dupe, but that doesn't apply here. 2. Is the problem well defined? If not, it's unclear, but that doesn't apply here either 3. Did the OP put in effort to solve the problem? Irrelevant, since that's not a reason to close. Also, IIUC, your issue is that the OP put in *too much* effort, right? If they hadn't mentioned extensions, you would not assume that they had looked for inbuilt solutions, and that would make the question on-topic?

Comment: Mate, you can try to come at this from all kinds of angles, but that doesn't change the fact that the OP was clearly looking for an extension. The post was closed as it should be, and now you're making it borderline on-topic by removing the fact the OP wasn't looking for a built-in feature. You're deliberately making the question broader, knowing extensions are the _only_ answer there. It's not a high traffic question, it's not a spectacularly good question, so why bother reviving it like this? It's not "bad" that a question is closed. It's a perfectly valid state for a question to be in.

Comment: @Cerbrus As I said, it's not clear to me that the OP was looking only for an extension. In fact, if they got an answer that explained how to do it with inbuilt settings, they would probably be quite happy. As to reopening it, it's an on-topic question in it's current form, so I see no reason to leave it closed. Being "open" is also a perfectly valid state for a question to be in, and if it's on-topic that *should* be the state it's in, regardless of the traffic, etc. Also, 37 upvotes and 4k views in 3 years is reasonably high traffic I would think.

Comment: Seriously? _" it's not clear to me that the OP was looking for an extension."_? OP tagged it with [tag:vscode-extensions], and explicitly asked _"Is there an extension that would let me do it?"_, which _you_ edited out...

Comment: @Cerbrus The [vscode-extensions] was a mistag, and was rightly edited out (it's meant for extension development, not usage). Like I said, the OP probably simply doesn't know that asking for extensions only is off-topic. Since asking the question without extensions is on-topic, it seems much more expedient to just edit that part out, instead of asking a brand new question. BTW, editing questions that look like resource requests into questions that are "how-to" is something that's done quite frequently (at least in SOCVR, when they come up).

Comment: A mistag the OP added _deliberatly_, as he quite likely didn't read the description.